# SKAction runBlock doesn't seem to be working as expected

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, stack-overflow, skaction

```
        let randomize = SKAction.runBlock({ [unowned self] in
            self.footstepFile = "Content/footstep\(RandomInt(1, max: 4))"
            print(self.footstepFile)
        })


        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([randomize, SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(footstepFile, waitForCompletion: true)])), withKey: "footsteps")
```

When this action runs, the footstepFile shows its randomizing when I print it, but in reality it's just playing the same sound file over and over. Why is this?

I play this action whenever the sprite is moving, and pause it whenever he stops. When it pauses and unpauses the footstepFile changes but if I'm continuously running, it just plays the same one over and over. Shouldn't the runblock be randomizing it continuously?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the `footstepFile` that is active when the `SKAction.sequence` is created is the one that is used repeatedly.  This is because the sequence only gets created once, and then used repeatedly.

To solve this, try creating an array of `playSoundFileNamed` actions all using random file names and pass that to `SKAction.sequence`:

```
var actions = [SKAction]()

for _ in 1...16 {
    footstepFile = "Content/footstep\(RandomInt(1, max: 4))"
    actions.append(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(footstepFile, waitForCompletion: true))
}

sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(actions)), withKey: "footsteps")
```

Comment: I get an exception on the SKAction.playSoundFileNamed() line with this. EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Oh wait, fixed this...was because I'm not running the action just declaring it.

Comment: Yeah this still isn't working though, I think it's trying to run so many times so fast that it crashes

Comment: I changed my answer with a different thing to try.